# Where to find the attribution name for a certain board?

Tags: arduino-uno, stm32

I'm working on lcd128x64 spi library. And was working with my Arduino Atmega328p chip.

Now I want to run the code with my maple mini board too.
So I have to specify the name on the pins for each chip board.
But I want to learn the basics of how to write these statements.

Could you tell me where to find the attributions for each board ?

For now I want to define the pin names for the Atmega328p and maple mini. This is my intention:

```
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__)
    #define CS_PIN                  10
    #define MOSI_PIN                11
    #define CLK_PIN                 13
#elif defined(STM32_SERIES_F1)  
    #define CS_PIN                  PB12
    #define MOSI_PIN                PB15
    #define CLK_PIN                 PB13
#endif
```

I don't think that's %100 correct, but I'm pretty sure that it's not the correct names of boards.

Comment: The whole point of the Arduino API is that you don't need to know the names of pins. You just need the numbers that the API assigns to them.

Comment: the SPI libraries know the pin numbers. you don't need to spceify them in normal case. the pins 11, 12, 13. are valid for Uno and Nano, not for ATmega328p.

Comment: Yeah I know but in my lcd128x64 library, I'm using both atmega328p and stm32 which is using other pins names and also it has two spi modules. Like, in this init function `void lcd128x64_init(void){
 pinMode(CS_PIN, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(CLK_PIN, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(MOSI_PIN, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(CS_PIN, LOW);       // disable CS_PIN
 SPI.begin();
 _delay_ms(100);          // initial delay
 digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);       // enable CS_PIN
...
}` the pins names are different, so I want to unify them in the header file.

Comment: Also spi2 initialization for stm32 is different `SPI_2.begin(); //Initialize the SPI_2 port.
  SPI_2.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST); // Set the SPI_2 bit order
  SPI_2.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0); //Set the  SPI_2 data mode 0
  SPI_2.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV16);  // Use a different speed to SPI 1
  pinMode(SPI2_NSS_PIN, OUTPUT);` so I have put that in my lcd128x64 lib

Comment: When I try to compile the code for the maple mini I get this:
`Arduino: 1.8.12 (Windows 10), Board: "Maple Mini, Original (17k RAM,108k Flash), 72MHz (Normal), Smallest (default)"

H:\Programming\Program_Files\Arduino\libraries\lcd128x64_spi\lcd128x64_spi.cpp:14:20: fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory

 #include <avr/io.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Maple Mini.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.`

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino defines to identify a board are in form of `ARDUINO_<board>`, where `<board>` is the value from `<x>.build.board` from boards.txt for board `<x>`

For example for Arduino AVR boards, in the boards.txt file is `uno.build.board=AVR_UNO` so the define is `ARDUINO_AVR_UNO`.

And Arduino has ['architecture' identification define](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification#working-with-multiple-architectures) too. This has form of `ARDUINO_ARCH_<arch.name>`. The `<arch.name>` is the uppercase version of the folder name with the boards package version. For example AVR for packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21.

Comment: But I want the specific attribution that are like in this link. @https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/using_tools_1using_avr_gcc_mach_opt.html@ I want the same for the STM32 I couldn't find its attribution.

Comment: @R1S8K, use arduino board or architecture identification, not the chip identification.

Comment: OK but I get now fatal error that including the avr/io .. `Arduino: 1.8.12 (Windows 10), Board: "Maple Mini, Original (17k RAM,108k Flash), 72MHz (Normal), Smallest (default)"

H:\Programming\Program_Files\Arduino\libraries\lcd128x64_spi\lcd128x64_spi.cpp:14:20: fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory

 #include <avr/io.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Maple Mini.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.` What to do now ?

Comment: @R1S8K, ask a new question

Comment: OK I'm trying to solve it before asking a new question.

Comment: How to use the board identification ?

Comment: @R1S8K, instead of `__AVR_ATmega328P__` use `ARDUINO_AVR_UNO` for pin mapping defines

Comment: ok thanks I didn't care for the Arduino as it's already defined but I was searching for the stm32 attribution. I think I found it and it's basically working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Maple Mini, you may look in [this folder](https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32/tree/master/STM32F1/variants/maple_mini), you will found the pin mapping between STM32 and Arduino nomenclature.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I didn't notice the rest of the name ! I thought they are just STM chips but I found the maple mini folder there, but also couldn't find the right attribution.

Comment: I don't get what you are looking for: is not enough this
 {&gpiob,   NULL, NULL, 11, 0, ADCx}, /* D0/PB11 */ ?

Comment: Maybe the *official* repo is cleaner: look at [this file](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/master/variants/MAPLEMINI_F103CB/variant.h)

Comment: @fabuiz7 thank you so much for your help. I'm actually found part of the solution which is just to use what I put in the main post which is `STM32_SERIES_F1` it worked, but I'm getting other errors that I'm trying now to solve them.

Comment: try this define, for me it worked ;) ARDUINO_MAPLEMINI_F103CB

Comment: Nope it got me this error list: `error: 'CS_PIN' was not declared in this scope

  pinMode(CS_PIN, OUTPUT);

error: 'CLK_PIN' was not declared in this scope

  pinMode(CLK_PIN, OUTPUT);

error: 'MOSI_PIN' was not declared in this scope

  pinMode(MOSI_PIN, OUTPUT);

error: 'delay_ms' was not declared in this scope

  delay_ms(100);          // trying initial delay`

Comment: Which Arduino Core are you using? I had installed [this one](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32)

Comment: How to post a link ? Sorry I don't know how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105417/discussion-between-r1s8k-and-fabiuz7).